# Find the increasing subsequence with maximum sum

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I`m trying to find the sub-array (also: subsequence) of an array. So far I found the correct maximal sum, but don't know how to find the elements themselves.
For example:

input= [10,70,20,30,50,11,30]
output = [110, [10,20,30,50]]

My code finds the 110, but I got difficulties to find the elements.
My code:

```js
const maxSubequence = (arr) => {
  let i, j;
  let msis = arr.slice(); //Copy input array

  //result variables
  let resultSeq = [];
  let maxSum = 0;
  let result = [];

  /* Compute maximum sum values in bottom up manner */
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[j] && msis[i] < msis[j] + arr[i]) {
        msis[i] = msis[j] + arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  // console.log(tempSeq);
  /* Pick maximum of all  msis values */
  let maxIndex = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < msis.length; i++) {
    if (maxSum < msis[i]) {
      maxSum = msis[i];
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }
  //Retrieve the max sequence elements using msis max sums - NOT WORKING
  var tempSeq = [msis[maxIndex]];
  resultSeq = [arr[maxIndex]];
  for (i = maxIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (msis[i] < tempSeq[0]) {
      tempSeq.unshift(msis[i])
      resultSeq.unshift(arr[i])
    }
  }
  result = [maxSum, resultSeq];
  return result;

}

console.log(
  maxSubequence([10, 70, 20, 30, 50, 11, 30])
)
```

Comment: will you share some input & output samples?

Comment: arrayTwo = [30,20, 10,50]; output : [60 , [10,50] ]

Comment: You generally need to maintain `maxSumStartIndex` and `maxSumEndIndex` (or `maxSumArrLength`).

Comment: maxSumStartIndex and maxSumEndIndex (or maxSumArrLength) - Already tried somthing similar but it`s not working

Comment: @חייםחדד Shouldn't the answer be [80, [30, 50] ] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        const findSum = arr =>{ 
            var sum = 0;
            arr.forEach(element=>{
                sum = sum + element
            });
            return sum;
        }



        const maxSubequenceSum = arr =>{

        // L[i] - The Maximum Sum Increasing
        // Subsequence that ends with arr[i]
        var L = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                L[i] = [];

        // L[0] is equal to arr[0]
        L[0].push(arr[0]);

        // Start from index 1
        for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

            // For each j less than i
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            /*
            * L[i] = {MaxSum(L[j])} + arr[i]
            where j < i and arr[j] < arr[i]
            */
                var sumLi = findSum(L[i]);
                var sumLj = findSum(L[j]);

                if ( (arr[i] > arr[j]) && (sumLi < sumLj) ) {
                    console.log(`${arr[i]} > ${arr[j]} && ${sumLi} < ${sumLj}`);
                    L[j].forEach( k=>{
                        if (!L[i].includes(k)){
                            L[i].push(k);
                            console.log(L);
                            
                        }     
                    });
                
                }
            }

            // L[i] ends with arr[i]

            L[i].push(arr[i]);

            // L[i] now stores Maximum Sum Increasing
            // Subsequence of arr[0..i] that ends with arr[i]

        }

        // res = L[0];
        var res = [L[0]];
        
        // Find max
        L.forEach( x =>{
            if (findSum(x) > findSum(res))
                res = x;

        });

        // Results variables
        var max = 0;
        var subSequence=[];
        var result;

        //Summing res elements = Max sum
        //Each res element = subsequence 
        res.forEach(i=>{
            max = max + i;
            subSequence.push(i);
        });


        result = [max,subSequence];
        //Time complexity: O(n^2))
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is O(n^3) time due to your `findsum` function. The solution in my answer to produce the increasing sum sequence is better as it is O(n^2) time. Also it only takes O(n) extra space while your solution takes O(n^2) extra space.

Answer (score 1):

Consider bookmarking the index `i` where previous max increasing sum sequence ended which current number at index `j` extends. If the current number doesn't extend any previous sequence set it -1. Now after finding the index of maximum sum, you can go back using the bookmarks until the index becomes -1. The reversed array would be your expected maximum increasing sum sequence.

```js
const maxSubequence = (arr) => {
  let i, j;
  let msis = arr.slice(); //Copy input array

  //result variables
  let resultSeq = [];
  let maxSum = 0;
  let result = [];
  var bookmark = new Array(arr.length);
  bookmark[0] = -1;
  /* Compute maximum sum values in bottom up manner */
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    bookmark[i] = -1;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[j] && msis[i] < msis[j] + arr[i]) {
        msis[i] = msis[j] + arr[i];
        bookmark[i] = j;
      }
    }
  }
  // console.log(tempSeq);
  /* Pick maximum of all  msis values */
  let maxIndex = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < msis.length; i++) {
    if (maxSum < msis[i]) {
      maxSum = msis[i];
      maxIndex = i;
    }
  }

  resultSeq = [arr[maxIndex]];
  for (i = bookmark[maxIndex]; i >= 0; i = bookmark[i]) {
      resultSeq.unshift(arr[i])
  }
  result = [maxSum, resultSeq];
  return result;

}

console.log(
  maxSubequence([30,20, 10,50])
)
```